# Correct setup for cross-domain Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I can't imagine this is an uncommon problem, but we keep running into challenges.

We have a campaign with a landing page on our site, with a form visitors can fill out. They give us their email, we email them some content. We want to track this as a single GA conversion.

Right now the setup has three pieces:
1) The campaign landing page on our web site
2) The actual form they fill out, which is in an iframe and hosted on a subdomain (info.MMMM.com instead of www.MMMM.com) (this form is managed and hosted by marketing automation service Pardot)
3) The "Thank You" page to which users are redirected once they fill out the form. This is on the main domain, not the subdomain.

We're using Universal Analytics, I believe. We have the stock UA snippet in the overall site footer, so it already appears on both the landing page and the thank-you page.

We have a cross-domain issues, in that right now info.MMMM.com appears as a high-traffic referrer. Of course this is wrong -- that's our own subdomain, and it's masking the real referrer.

I've been following Pardot's instructions for cross-domain tracking. In doing so, I added our UA code snippet to the code generator for the iframed form. This works, but the Google Tag Assistant then tells me I have two GA tags for the same property (one in the iframe and one in the overall page footer I guess).

Am I headed up the wrong tree? Should I just be following the guidelines for "Cross domain auto linking for forms" on this Google page?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,

SGL

Comment: In your question, you failed to mentioned were the "Thank you" page is located. If its located on your site/sub domain, then tracking it should be easy to setup a goal in analytics everytime some one hits that page. 

For your cross domain tracking / subdomain tracking issue. From your note - looks like your subdomain is setup correctly, because your sub is supposed to show as referer in your traffic source, otherwise how do you know your are getting traffic from it. If you don't want it to show then just add a filter. 

For the Pardot - follow their instructions not the link you posted

Comment: Sorry, good point. The TY page is on the main domain, not the subdomain. As far as following Pardot's instructions -- that's what led me to include the Analytics code in the iframed form, which led to the "property appears twice" error. Sorry I didn't make this clear in the question.